# How to check multiple DropDown combination if is it duplicated record in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two DropDown list, and before saving i need to check combination is existing or not in database.
First DropDown select some DatesList  which is saved in related database by ID, Second DropDown is list of any Person also recorded in related database by ID.

Now i need to check and back errorMessage if conmbination exist.
  I have this code but i thing this is just for TextBox-es only:

DropDown in View:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("DateID", null, "- DATE -", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", required="required" })

 @Html.DropDownList("personID",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AllStockList, "--PESRON--", htmlAttributes: new { @required = "required" })
```

Here is Code in Model:

```
[Remote("RezChk", "rezervacii")]
public int DateID { get; set; }

[Remote("RezChk", "rezervacii", ErrorMessage = "RECORD COMBINATION EXIST.")]
 public int personID { get; set; }
```

And here is code in controller:

```
public JsonResult RezChk(int PersonID, int DateID)
{
return Json(!db.tbl_rezervacii.Any(x => x.PersonID == PersonID && x.DateID == DateID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

**My Question:**
I have 3 tables here.

1. users
2. list of dates and
3. table where i save some records combination.

   Now if i add one records for **user1** and second dropdown **Date1**. Now i need to check and stop record if exist combination for **user1** and **Date1**. and if for **user1** is choiced **Date2** to add new record. or any **user2** if for first time choice **Date1** also to add record. i need to check combination and not allow to duplicate by that combination.

   How to solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean "not work"?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why you are storing those values in the database and after throw an error to the user. We can help you better if you clear the question properly.

Comment: i have 3 tables here. 1. users 2 list if dates and 3 is table where i  save some records combination. now if i add one records for user1 and secund dropdown Date1. now i need to check and stop record again for user1 and Date1. and if for user1 is choiced Date2 to add new record. or any user2 if for first time choice Date1 also to add record. i need to check combination and not allow to duplicate by that combination.

Comment: It's better to present the remaining options in the other dropdown list if an option in one dropdown list has been made. Look for *cascading dropdown lists*. Check for duplicates in the backend just for sure.

Comment: You can even go for creating a composite unique key for the columns you want the combinations to be unique, and catch the `DbUpdateException` in case you encounter a duplicate combination....However, it is better to restrict those entries before sending to the database, than relying on the database to do it for you...

Answer (score 0):

return Json(db.tbl_rezervacii.Any(x => x.PersonID == PersonID || x.DateID == DateID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);